# How would I find the amount of frequencies that fall below a criteria in R?

Tags: r

I created a table that shows me how many values of each appear in my dataframe

```
neighborhood_table = sort(table(airbnb_eurasia_usa$neighbourhood),decreasing = TRUE)
```

How would I use this to count how many values appear 20 or fewer times?

Answer (score 2):

You have this situation:

```
mtcars$cyl
# [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4

table(mtcars$cyl)
#  4  6  8 
# 11  7 14
```

We may check how many *levels* appear less than `12` times using `<`,

```
table(mtcars$cyl) < 12
#    4     6     8 
# TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

and `sum` the boolean result, where `FALSE == 0` and `TRUE == 1`.

```
sum(table(mtcars$cyl) < 12)
# [1] 2
```

Whereas, if we want to count how many *values* are below say `6`, we do

```
sum(mtcars$cyl < 6)
# [1] 11
```